# Finding $r$ given differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y(x)=e^{rx}$. And we have following differential equations:

(1) $y'+y=e^x+e^{-x}$

(2) $y'+2y=e^{-x}$.

Then after substitution we get

(1) $re^{rx}+e^{rx}=e^x+e^{-x}$

(2) $re^{rx}+2e^{rx}=e^{-x}$

Is it safe to conclude that there is no such $r$ that satisfies (1) or (2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are linear ODE solve them by finding integrating function
The solution of $y'+Py_=Q$ is given by $$y=I(x)^{-1} \int I(x) Q(x) dx+ A I(x)^{-1}, I(x)=e^{\int p(x) dx}.$$
Here for
(1) $$y'+y=e^{x}+e^{-x}\implies y=e^{-x}\int e^{x}(e^{x}+e^{-x}) dx+C e^{-x} \implies y=e^{-x} (e^{2x}/2+1)+Ce^{-x} \implies y=e^{x}/2+Ae^{-x}$$